# Script# preprocessor directives?

Tags: javascript, script#

does anyone know the preprocessor directives that are available for use in the script.jst file. I am trying to write the filename of the generated js file to the generated .js file.
ie. script.js or script.debug.js

Thanks

Donal

Answer (score 0):

The file being generated isn't available as a variable to output, but its a good idea, and fits with the work I am currently doing in the script# compiler/preprocessor.

I'll look into adding that in either the next release or the one after that.

Comment: I have added the following for the next build:

#= ScriptFile ##